# Changing dependent drop down input options on dynamically added rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm working in OpenCart MVC and I have a form that has a section that allows for rows of inputs to be added. Each row on submitting becomes its own record. [Input drop-down Status] needs to be dependent on [Input drop-down Type]. If [Input drop-down Type] is email then [Input drop down] would show one set of options and if [Input drop-down Type] shows Event then [Input drop-down Status] would show a different set of options.

I have a working [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon_guy/full/XzKQKw/) of how this should work.

The problem I'm having is adding this into my code. The rows are added onto the form using JQuery. each row has a component_row incremental to allow for individual records. I tried adding the SELECT name to the Script Im using but so far I cannot seem to get it to work correctly(does not change input options).

Currently, on the form, the Input Type shows its correct options( read from a table) however the Input Status is blank and making a choice on Input Type does not affect Input Status at all(it does in the code)pen 
The HTML code section shows existing records when visited through the edit controller. On the Add controller, there are no rows initially, a user can add as many as they'd like by clicking the plus button. These rows are added through the first Script I listed
VIEW:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title"><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
            <?php echo $text_add_component; ?>
        </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" id="addon">
        <div class=" col-lg-10 col-lg-push-1 form-group">
            <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-special">
                <div class="table-responsive" id="component-module">
                    <table id="components" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <td class="text-left">
                                    <?php echo $entry_name; ?>
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-left">
                                    <?php echo $text_filter_type; ?>
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-left">
                                    <?php echo $entry_status; ?>
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-left">
                                    <?php echo $entry_owner; ?>
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-left">
                                    <?php echo $entry_component_start_date; ?>
                                </td>
                                <td></td>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <?php $component_row = 0;?>
                            <?php if (isset($component_modules)) {?>
                            <?php foreach ($component_modules as $component_module) {?>
                            <tr id="component-row<?php echo $component_row; ?>">
                                <td class="text-left"><input type="text" name="component_module[<?php echo $component_row; ?>][component_name]"
                                        value="<?php echo $component_module['component_name']; ?>" class="form-control" />
                                </td>

                                <td class="text-left">
                                    <div class="component-dropdowns"><select name="component_module[<?php echo $component_row; ?>][component_type]"
                                            class="form-control">
                                            <?php foreach ($component_groups as $component_group) {?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $component_group['group_type']; ?>" <?php echo ($component_module['component_type'] == $component_group['group_type']) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>
                                                <?php echo $component_group['group_type']; ?>
                                            </option>
                                            <?php }?>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                                <td class="text-left">
                                    <div class="component-dropdowns"><select name="component_module[<?php echo $component_row; ?>][component_status]"
                                            class="form-control">
                                            <?php foreach ($component_status as $status) {?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $status['status_type']; ?>" <?php echo ($component_module['component_status'] == $status['status_type']) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>
                                                <?php echo $status['status_type']; ?>
                                            </option>
                                            <?php }?>
                                        </select></div>

                                </td>
                                <td class="text-left">
                                    <div class="component-dropdowns"><select name="component_module[<?php echo $component_row; ?>][component_owner]"
                                            class="form-control">
                                            <?php foreach ($users as $user) {?>
                                            <option value="<?php echo $user['username']; ?>" <?php echo ($component_module['component_owner'] == $user['username']) ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>
                                                <?php echo $user['username']; ?>
                                            </option>
                                            <?php }?>
                                        </select></div>

                                </td>
                                <td class="text-left">
                                    <div class="input-group date required"><input type="text" name="component_module[<?php echo $component_row; ?>][component_start_date]"
                                            value="<?php echo $component_module['component_start_date']; ?>"
                                            data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD" class="form-control" /><span class="input-group-btn"
                                            id="component-calendar-btn"><button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i
                                                    class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button></span></div>

                                </td>
                                <input type="hidden" name="component_module[<?php echo $component_row; ?>][component_parent_id]"
                                    value="<?php echo $component_module['parent_id']; ?>" class="form-control" />
                                <td class="text-left"><button type="button" onclick="$('#component-row<?php echo $component_row; ?>').remove();"
                                        data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" class="btn btn-danger"><i
                                            class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button></td>
                            </tr>


                            <?php $component_row++;?>
                            <?php }?>
                            <?php } else {?>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="5" class="text-center">No components </td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php }?>

                        </tbody>
                        <tfoot>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="5"></td>
                                <td class="text-right"><button type="button" onclick="addComponents();" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                        title="<?php echo $button_add; ?>" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i></button></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tfoot>
                    </table>
                    <?php if ($error_component_name) {?>
                    <div class="text-danger">
                        <?php echo $error_component_name; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php }?>
                    <?php if ($error_component_type) {?>
                    <div class="text-danger">
                        <?php echo $error_component_type; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php }?>
                    <?php if ($error_component_status) {?>
                    <div class="text-danger">
                        <?php echo $error_component_status; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php }?>
                    <?php if ($error_component_owner) {?>
                    <div class="text-danger">
                        <?php echo $error_component_owner; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php }?>
                    <?php if ($error_date_beginning) {?>
                    <div class="text-danger">
                        <?php echo $error_date_beginning; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php }?>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var component_row = <?php echo $component_row; ?>;
function addComponents(language_id) {
    html = '  <tr id="component-row' + component_row + '">';
    html += '  <td class="text-right"><input type="text" name="component_module[' + component_row + '][component_name]" value="" class="form-control" /></td>';
    html += '  <td class="text-right component-dropdown"><div class="component-dropdowns"> <select name="component_module[' + component_row + '][component_type]" id="bobo" ><option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option><option value="Email"><?php echo "Email" ?></option><option value="Text Message"><?php echo "Text Message" ?></option><option value="Direct Mail"><?php echo "Direct Mail" ?></option><option value="Transnational Email"><?php echo "Transnational Email" ?></option><option value="EVENT"><?php echo "Event" ?></option> </select><div></td>';
    html += '  <td class="text-right component-dropdown"><div class="component-dropdowns"> <select name="component_module[' + component_row + '][component_status]" id="youda" ></select><div></td>';
    html += '  <td class="text-right component-dropdown"><div class="component-dropdowns"> <select name="component_module[' + component_row + '][component_owner]" ><option value=""><?php echo $text_select; ?></option><?php foreach ($users as $user) {?><option value="<?php echo $user['
    username ']; ?>" ><?php echo $user['
    username ']; ?></option><?php }?>  </select></div></td>';
    html += '  <td class="text-right" id="comp-cal"><div class="input-group date required"><input type="text" name="component_module[' + component_row + '][component_start_date]" placeholder="<?php echo $entry_date; ?>" data-date-format="YYYY-MM-DD"  class="form-control" /><span class="input-group-btn" id="component-calendar-btn">';
    html += '  <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button></span></div></td>';

    html += '  <td class="text-left"><button type="button" onclick="$(\'#component-row' + component_row + '\').remove();" data-toggle="tooltip" title="<?php echo $button_remove; ?>" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-minus-circle"></i></button></td>';
    html += '</tr>';
    html += '  <input type="hidden" name="component_module[' + component_row + '][code]" value="<?php echo $code; ?>" class="form-control" readonly />';

    $('#components tbody').append(html);
    $('.date').datetimepicker({
        formatDate: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        formatDate: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        pickTime: false
    });
    component_row++;
}


$("component_module[' + component_row + '][component_type]").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Email') {
        $("component_module[' + component_row + '][component_status]")
            .empty()
            .append($('<option>', {
                value: 'draft',
                text: 'Draft'
            }))
            .append($('<option>', {
                value: 'sent',
                text: 'Sent'
            }))
            .append($('<option>', {
                value: 'saved',
                text: 'Saved'
            }));


    } else if ($(this).val() == 'Text Message') {
        $("component_module[' + component_row + '][component_status]")
            .empty()
            .append($('<option>', {
                value: 'draft',
                text: 'Draft'
            }))
            .append($('<option>', {
                value: 'sent',
                text: 'Sent'
            }))
            .append($('<option>', {
                value: 'saved',
                text: 'Saved'
            }));

    } else if ($(this).val() == 'Direct Mail') {
        $("component_module[' + component_row + '][component_status]")
            .empty()
            .append($('<option>', {
                value: 'draft',
                text: 'Draft'
            }))
            .append($('<option>', {
                value: 'sent',
                text: 'Sent'
            }))
            .append($('<option>', {
                value: 'saved',
                text: 'Saved'
            }));

    } else if ($(this).val() == 'Transnational Email') {
        $("component_module[' + component_row + '][component_status]")
            .empty()
            .append($('<option>', {
                value: 'draft',
                text: 'Draft'
            }))
            .append($('<option>', {
                value: 'sent',
                text: 'Sent'
            }))
            .append($('<option>', {
                value: 'saved',
                text: 'Saved'
            }));

    } else {
        $("component_module[' + component_row + '][component_status]")
            .empty()
            .append($('<option>', {
                value: 'draft',
                text: 'Draft'
            }))
            .append($('<option>', {
                value: 'scheduled',
                text: 'Scheduled'
            }))
            .append($('<option>', {
                value: 'sent',
                text: 'Sent'
            }));

    }
});
      //--></script>
```

This image shows what a new row looks like. A user can add as many as the'd like. On submit each row is written as its own record to the db[image]

Comment: i cant get what problem you are having , what do you mean by "cannot add into my code" your codepen example that is working do you want to replicate it in the form of several rows as shown in the picture and then and then on clicking submit you want all of them to be saved and that too as a separate record for each row, are you able to add the rows dynamically? or are you stucked at saving all of them as a separate records in the database?

Comment: the row featured in the image is produced by the first Script I provided. The second script is supposed to change the options for the input Status depending on what the user chooses in the previous input Type. I added what I thought would be the code into the html of the Javascript function. This is not working the status dropdown is empty and does not change based on Type options

Answer (score 0):

You are using `.html()` to update your select dropdown whereas should it be like for example

```
var options = ['option1', 'option2', 'option3'];
var select = $('#city');
for (i = 0; 1 < options.length; i++) {
    select.empty().append($('<option>', {
        value: i,
        text: options[i]
    }));
}
```

or if in your code it would be

```
$('SELECT[name=component_module[' + component_row + '][component_status]]')
    .empty()
    .append($('<option>', {
        value: 'draft',
        text: 'Draft'
    }))
    .append($('<option>', {
        value: 'sent',
        text: 'Sent'
    }))
    .append($('<option>', {
        value: 'saved',
        text: 'Saved'
    }));
```